# How can I access a field from a Module by using a variable?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am using a module to hold repeated code, but I need to pass in a field as a parameter that can be changed. I have used `Form1.controls(variableName & ".text")` to accomplish the same thing with text boxes, but it will not work for fields as they are not controls. Here is the code I used for text boxes:

```
Public Sub fillTextBox(table As DataTable, column As String, value As String, txtNum As Integer)
        For i As Integer = 0 To table.Rows.Count() - 1
            If table.Rows(i)(column) = value Then
                Form1.Controls("Text" & (txtNum).ToString()).Text = table.Rows(i)("VALUE")
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

And this is where I would like to use a field from Form1:

```
Public Sub getData(table As DataTable, column As String, value As String, destination As String, bError As String)
    For i As Integer = 0 To table.Rows.Count() - 1
        If table.Rows(i)(column) = value Then
            Form1.Controls(destination) = table.Rows(i)(column)
            Form1.found = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
        Form1.Controls(bError) = True
    End If
    Form1.found = False
End Sub
```

"destination" and "bError" are fields that are passed into the Function, but they will be different fields depending on what table is being used and what field needs filled.

Comment: You should use a `Dictionary` instead.

Comment: @SLaks Ok. I'm fairly new to visual studio, so I haven't used one of those yet. Is there somewhere you would recommend looking for my purposes, or just start on the MSDN page about it?